# Maximum Likelihood Estimation of a Wishart Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, roots, estimation, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

A Wishart distribution is defined as:

\begin{equation}
 f \left( \Lambda | {V}, \nu \right) = \mathcal{W}\left( V , \nu  \right) = \frac{ \left| \Lambda  \right|^{\frac{\nu -p-1}{2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \text{tr}\left( \Lambda {V}^{-1} \right) }     }{ 2^{\frac{ \nu p}{2}} \left| {V} \right|^{\frac{\nu}{2}} \Gamma_{p}\left( \frac{\nu}{2} \right)   }
\end{equation}

We suppose that we have $M$ precision matrces $\Lambda_{m}$. We assume that each matrix is drawn independently from the same $\mathcal{W}\left( V , \nu  \right)$. Therefore, we can model the joint distribution of the precision matrices as:

\begin{equation}
 f \left( \Lambda_{1}, \Lambda_{2}, \ldots, \Lambda_{M} | {V}, \nu \right) = \prod_{m=1}^{M} \mathcal{W}\left( V , \nu  \right) =  \prod_{m=1}^{M} \frac{ \left| \Lambda_{m}  \right|^{\frac{\nu -p-1}{2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \text{tr}\left( \Lambda_{m} {V}^{-1} \right) }     }{ 2^{\frac{ \nu p}{2}} \left| {V} \right|^{\frac{\nu}{2}} \Gamma_{p}\left( \frac{\nu}{2} \right)   }
\end{equation}

I want to find the maximum likelihood estimates of $V$ and $\nu$. They are given in the proofs below. However, when I try to solve the equation for $\nu$, I am not getting the correct answer.

```
import numpy
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.special as special
import scipy.stats as stats


#===Make Wishart RVS===#
p = 3
nu = 4.5
V = numpy.eye(p)
wishart = stats.wishart(df=int(float(nu)), scale=V)

#===Sample From Wishart and Calculate Constant C===#
dets = []
C = 0.0
M = 1000
for m in range(M):
    A = wishart.rvs()
    dets.append(numpy.linalg.det(A))
    C += numpy.log(dets[m])
C -= M*(p*numpy.log(2) + numpy.log(numpy.linalg.det(V)))

#===Show Calculation===#
vs = numpy.linspace(nu-1.5, nu+1.5, 101)
vals = []
for v in vs:
    summ = sum( [ special.digamma( (v - k - 1)/2.0 ) for k in range(0, int(p)+1  )])
    vals.append(summ - C/M)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(vs,vals)
plt.axhline(0, color='black')
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot is here:

[image: Resulting Plot]

As you can see, the zero point is not at 4.5, as it should be.

**Question:**

What is going on? How do we actually compute $\nu$ given $V$?

---

**Proof: Finding $V$**

We find $V$ via maximum likelihood. So we have:

\begin{equation}
 f \left( \Lambda_{1}, \Lambda_{2}, \ldots, \Lambda_{M} | {V}, \nu \right) = K \cdot \prod_{m=1}^{M} | V |^{-\frac{\nu}{2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \text{tr}\left( \Lambda_{m} {V}^{-1} \right) }
\end{equation}

where $K$ is a constant that does not depend on $V$. Taking the logarithm, we get:

\begin{equation}
 \text{log}\left( \cdot \right) = \text{log}\left(K \right) + \sum_{m=1}^{M} -\frac{\nu}{2} \text{log}\left( | V |  \right) - \frac{1}{2} \text{tr}\left( \Lambda_{m} {V}^{-1} \right)
\end{equation}

Taking the derivative, we get:

\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial }{ \partial V }\text{log}\left( \cdot \right) & =  \sum_{m=1}^{M} -\frac{\nu}{2} V^{-1} + \frac{1}{2} V^{-1} \Lambda_{m} V^{-1} = 0 \\
 & =  -\nu M V^{-1} + \sum_{m=1}^{M} V^{-1} \Lambda_{m} V^{-1} = 0
\end{align}

We then right multiply by $V$, giving us:

\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial }{ \partial V }\text{log}\left( \cdot \right) & =  -\nu M {I}  + \sum_{m=1}^{M} V^{-1} \Lambda_{m}  = 0 \\
 &= \sum_{m=1}^{M} V^{-1} \Lambda_{m} = \nu M {I}
\end{align}

Now left multiplying by $V$, we get:

\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial }{ \partial V }\text{log}\left( \cdot \right) &= \sum_{m=1}^{M}  \Lambda_{m} = V \nu M {I}
\end{align}

So we get:

\begin{equation}
 \boxed{ V = \frac{1}{\nu M} {I} \cdot \sum_{m=1}^{M}  \Lambda_{m}}
\end{equation}

---

**Proof: Finding $\nu$**

We find $\nu$ via maximum likelihood. So we have:

\begin{align}
f \left( \Lambda_{1}, \Lambda_{2}, \ldots, \Lambda_{M} | {V}, \nu \right) &  =  \prod_{m=1}^{M} \frac{ \left| \Lambda_{m}  \right|^{\frac{\nu -p-1}{2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \text{tr}\left( \Lambda_{m} {V}^{-1} \right) }     }{ 2^{\frac{ \nu p}{2}} \left| {V} \right|^{\frac{\nu}{2}} \Gamma_{p}\left( \frac{\nu}{2} \right)   } \\
 f \left( \Lambda_{1}, \Lambda_{2}, \ldots, \Lambda_{M} | {V}, \nu \right) & = K \cdot  \prod_{m=1}^{M} \frac{ \left| \Lambda_{m}  \right|^{\frac{\nu -p-1}{2}}      }{ 2^{\frac{ \nu p}{2}} \left| {V} \right|^{\frac{\nu}{2}} \Gamma_{p}\left( \frac{\nu}{2} \right)   } \\
 f \left( \Lambda_{1}, \Lambda_{2}, \ldots, \Lambda_{M} | {V}, \nu \right) & = K \cdot \left[ 2^{\frac{ \nu p }{2}} \left| {V} \right|^{\frac{\nu }{2}} \Gamma_{p}\left( \frac{\nu}{2} \right) \right]^{-M}  \cdot \prod_{m=1}^{M} \left| \Lambda_{m}  \right|^{\frac{\nu -p-1}{2}}     \\
\end{align}

where $K$ is a constant that does not depend on $\nu$. Taking the logarithm, we get:

\begin{align}
 \text{log}\left( \cdot \right) & = \text{log}\left( K \right) + \frac{\nu - p - 1}{2} \sum_{m=1}^{M}  \text{log}\left( |\Lambda_{m}| \right) - M \cdot \left[ \frac{\nu p}{2} \text{log}\left( 2 \right) + \frac{\nu}{2} \text{log}\left( | V | \right) + \text{log} \left( \Gamma_{p} \left( \frac{\nu}{2} \right) \right) \right]   \\
 \text{log}\left( \cdot \right) & = \text{log}\left( K \right) +  \frac{\nu}{2} \sum_{m=1}^{M}  \text{log}\left( |\Lambda_{m}| \right) - \frac{p-1}{2} \sum_{m=1}^{M} \text{log}\left( |\Lambda_{m}| \right) - M \nu \cdot \left[ \frac{p}{2} \text{log}\left( 2 \right) + \frac{1}{2} \text{log}\left( | V | \right) \right] - M \text{log} \left( \Gamma_{p} \left( \frac{\nu}{2} \right) \right) 
\end{align}

Now taking the derivative with respect to $\nu$, setting the result equal to zero, and multiplying both sides by $2$, we get:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial }{\partial \nu} \text{log}\left( \cdot \right) & = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{m=1}^{M}  \text{log}\left( |\Lambda_{m}| \right) - M \cdot \left[ \frac{p}{2} \text{log}\left( 2 \right) + \frac{1}{2} \text{log}\left( | V | \right) \right] - M \frac{\partial }{\partial \nu} \text{log} \left( \Gamma_{p} \left( \frac{\nu}{2} \right) \right)
\end{align}

If we let $C =  \sum_{m=1}^{M}  \text{log}\left( |\Lambda_{m}| \right) - M \cdot \left[ p \cdot \text{log}\left( 2 \right) +  \text{log}\left( | V | \right) \right] $, then:

\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial }{ \partial \nu} \text{log} \left( \Gamma_{p} \left( \frac{\nu}{2} \right) \right) = \frac{C}{2M}
\end{align}

Now:

\begin{align}
 \Gamma_{p} \left( \frac{\nu}{2} \right)  = \pi^{\frac{p(p-1)}{4}} \prod_{k=1}^{p} \Gamma \left( \frac{\nu - k - 1}{2}  \right)
\end{align}

So:

\begin{align}
 \text{log} \left( \Gamma_{p} \left( \frac{\nu}{2} \right) \right) & =  \text{log}\left(  \pi^{\frac{p(p-1)}{4}} \prod_{k=1}^{p} \Gamma \left( \frac{\nu - k - 1}{2}  \right) \right) \\
 \text{log} \left( \Gamma_{p} \left( \frac{\nu}{2} \right) \right) & = \frac{p(p-1)}{4} \cdot \text{log}\left(\pi  \right) + \sum_{k=1}^{p} \text{log}\left( \Gamma \left( \frac{\nu - k - 1}{2}  \right) \right)
\end{align}

Therefore:

\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial }{ \partial \nu} \text{log} \left( \Gamma_{p} \left( \frac{\nu}{2} \right) \right) =  \sum_{k=1}^{p} \frac{1}{2} \psi \left( \frac{\nu - k - 1}{2} \right) 
\end{align}

where $\psi(\cdot)$ is the digamma function. Therefore we need to solve:

\begin{align}
 \boxed{  \sum_{k=1}^{p} \psi \left( \frac{\nu - k - 1}{2} \right)  -  \frac{C}{M} = 0}
\end{align}

which, since the digamma function is monotonic over $\mathbb{R}_{++}$, can be done with a simple line search.